# popup dialog box in word addin

Tags: ms-word, vsto, add-in

I am creating a ms office word addin using c#. I have a ribbon with several button. On clicking one of the button I need a popup with few textboxes.
Question:  How to create a popup dialog in word addin?

Answer (score 3):

Add a new Form to your add-in project and design as desired.

In your button click handler you just need to do "new MyPopupDialog().Show();". If you want to make the Word window the parent of your dialog so you can centre it and make it modal to the word window you can make a window wrapper class that you can use in "new MyPopupDialog().ShowDialog(WordWindowWarper);". Something like this:

```
public class WindowWrapper : IWin32Window
{
    public WindowWrapper(IntPtr handle)
    {
        Handle = handle;
    }

    public IntPtr Handle { get; private set; }
}
```

The handle being the window handle of the Word application window.

Comment: "WordWindowWarper" - I love it :-)